# (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

Tags: java, spring-boot

After adding the **ProductServiceUtils**  class started throwinf this error...

This is the controller

```
package com.product.hexagonal.architecture.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import com.product.hexagonal.architecture.model.Product;
import com.product.hexagonal.architecture.service.ProductService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api")
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService ;
    private MultipartFile imageFile;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadImage(@RequestParam MultipartFile imageFile){
        this.imageFile = imageFile;
        productService.uploadToLocalFileSystem(imageFile);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(imageFile);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload/product", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Product> SaveProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        this.productService.uploadToLocalFileSystem(this.imageFile);
        this.productService.saveProduct(product);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(product);
    }
}
```

This is the Service

```
package com.product.hexagonal.architecture.service;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.product.hexagonal.architecture.model.Product;
import com.product.hexagonal.architecture.repository.ProductRepository;


@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductServiceUtils productServiceUtils;
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    private String fileDownloadUri;
    @Override
    public List<Product> getAll() {
        return productRepository.findAll() ;
    }
    @Override
    public void saveProduct(Product product) {
        product.setImageFile(this.fileDownloadUri);
        productRepository.save(product);
    }
    @Override
    public Product getOne(long id) {
    return productRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteProductById(long id) {
        productRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void uploadToLocalFileSystem(MultipartFile imageFile) {
    this.productServiceUtils.uploadToLocalFileSystem(imageFile);
    this.fileDownloadUri = (this.productServiceUtils.getFileDownloadUri());
    }

    @Override
    public  byte[] getImageWithMediaType(String fileName) {
        return this.productServiceUtils.getImageWithMediaType(fileName);
    }
    @Override
    public void update(Product product ) {
        this.productRepository.save(product);
    }
}
```

After adding this **ProductServiceUtils** class the error started...
When i had all code in **ProductService** class everythink was working ....

```
package com.product.hexagonal.architecture.service;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

@Service
public class ProductServiceUtils {
    
    private String fileDownloadUri;
    private String  fileName;
    private final String storageDirectoryPath = "C:\\opt\\spring-workspace\\Product-Hexagonal-Architecture\\Images";
    public ResponseEntity<String>  uploadToLocalFileSystem(MultipartFile imageFile) {
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(imageFile.getOriginalFilename());
        this.setFileName(fileName);
        Path storageDirectory = Paths.get(storageDirectoryPath);
        if(!Files.exists(storageDirectory)){
            try {
                Files.createDirectories(storageDirectory); 
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Path destination = Paths.get(storageDirectory.toString() + "\\" + fileName);
        try {
            Files.copy(imageFile.getInputStream(), destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("api/getImage/")
                .path(fileName)
                .toUriString();
        this.setFileDownloadUri(fileDownloadUri);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(fileDownloadUri); 
    }
    public  byte[] getImageWithMediaType(String imageName) {
        Path destination = Paths.get(storageDirectoryPath+"\\"+imageName);
        try {
            return IOUtils.toByteArray(destination.toUri());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null ;
    }
    public String getFileDownloadUri() {
        return fileDownloadUri;
    }
    public void setFileDownloadUri(String fileDownloadUri) {
        this.fileDownloadUri = fileDownloadUri;
    }
    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }
    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
    public String getStorageDirectoryPath() {
        return storageDirectoryPath;
    }
}
```

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile["inputStream"]->java.io.FileInputStream["fd"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1277) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1516) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1006) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:345) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:277) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I guess the problem is when i added the **ProductServiceUtils class**. Probably services comunication i dont know.....any idea???

Comment: What is the `return ResponseEntity.ok(imageFile)` supposed to do? Didn't you mean `return productService.uploadToLocalFileSystem(imageFile)`?

Comment: return productService.uploadToLocalFileSystem(imageFile) its working also.... its uploading a file in the server folder...and the link to be downloaded is stored in database..

Comment: Not sure I follow. Did that solve the problem or not?

Comment: Not yet.........

Comment: I'm confused again, what happened when you removed the `return ResponseEntity.ok(imageFile)` line and instead added `return` to the line just above it (`return productService.uploadToLocalFileSystem(imageFile)`)? Did you get a different error?

Comment: Nevermind, let me post an answer

Comment: I added just a return its throwing an error in front end but is working :P.... anyway i am gona fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th problem is you're trying to return `Response.ok(imageFile)` from your controller's `uploadImage` method. Spring then complains, because it doesn't know how to convert a `MultipartFile` into JSON.

Since `ProductServiceUtils.uploadToLocalFileSystem()` returns a `ResponseEntity<String>`, I believe what you had in mind was to return that value from the controller method, i.e.:

```
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    public ResponseEntity<String>uploadToLocalFileSystem(MultipartFile imageFile) {
        ResponseEntity<String> result = this.productServiceUtils.uploadToLocalFileSystem(imageFile);
        this.fileDownloadUri = (this.productServiceUtils.getFileDownloadUri());
        return result;
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api")
public class ProductController {
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadImage(@RequestParam MultipartFile imageFile){
        this.imageFile = imageFile;
        return productService.uploadToLocalFileSystem(imageFile);
    }
}
```

As a side note, you shouldn't be storing the state associated to the current invocation (`fileDownloadUri`, `imageFile`) inside singleton beans. This makes them non-thread-safe. Instead, design the API in such a way to include any relevant information in the return value.